# bundle.js still contains arrow function and default parameters after using babel pollyfill

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs, babel-polyfill

I have added many settings given by Babel or others from stack overflow but the new features of ES6 such as arrow function and default parameter are still in my bundle.js

The bundle.js has content like below:

```
    var nn = function(e={}) {
        const {baseClasses: t, newClasses: n, Component: r} = e;
        if (!n)
            return t;
        const a = At()({}, t);
        return Object.keys(n).forEach(e=>{
            n[e] && (a[e] = `${t[e]} ${n[e]}`)
        }
        ),
        a
    };
```

As a result, when I open my page in IE11, the error `missing ')'` happened which point to `function(e={})`.

Here is my webpack.config.js:

```
const entries = require("./config/pages").reduce(function(map, page) {
  map[page] = `./src/${page}/index.js`;
  return map;
}, {});

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: ["@babel/polyfill",...entries],

  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname,'dist'),
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'myapp/static/js/[name]/bundle.js'
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  module: require("./config/loaders"),
  devServer:{
    open: true,
    publicPath: '/',
    historyApiFallback: true,
    disableHostCheck: true
  },
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
        filename: "[name].css",
        chunkFilename: "[id].css"
    }),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        fetch: "isomorphic-fetch",
    })
  ]
};
```

and ./config/loaders for module

```
module.exports = {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
      // exclude: /node_modules/,
      loader: 'babel-loader',
    },
    {
      test: /\.(css|less)$/,
      use: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "less-loader"]
    },
    {
      test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
      use: [
        {
          loader: 'url-loader',
          options: {
            limit: 500, //small than 500 use url, otherwise use base64
            outputPath:'inquiry/static/img/'
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
      use: [{
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          outputPath: 'myapp/static/fonts/'
        }
      }]

    }
  ]
};
```

the .babelrc:

```
{
  "presets": [
    // ["@babel/env",
    //   {
    //     "targets": {
    //       "browsers": "ie 11"
    //     },      
    //     "useBuiltIns": "usage",
    //     "corejs": "3.0.1",
    //   }
    // ],
    ["@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "useBuiltIns": "entry",
        "corejs": "3.0.1",
      }],
    "@babel/react"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    ["@babel/transform-runtime"],
    ["@babel/plugin-transform-parameters"],
    ["@babel/plugin-transform-arrow-functions"],
    [
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators",
      {
        "legacy": true
      }
    ],
    [
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
      {
        "loose": true
      }
    ],
  ]
}
```

Also, I have imported '@babel/polyfill' in my index.js

PS: I have noticed that the code contains ES6 features is from Meterial UI lib in node_modules, so I deleted `exclude: /node_modules/,` in babel loader rule but it still does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are targeting specific browsers in the @babel/preset-env plugin, defined in the babel.config.js (which is a another way of declaring the babel configuration).

```
    presets: [
        [
            '@babel/preset-env',
            {
                modules: 'commonjs',
                useBuiltIns: 'entry',
                targets: {
                    chrome: '58',
                    firefox: '54',
                    ie: '11',
                    safari: '10',
                    opera: '44',
                    edge: '16'
                }
            }
        ],
        [
            '@babel/preset-react'
        ]
    ],
    plugins: [
        '@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import',
        '@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties'
    ]
```

Please try the target declaration like I posted above.
We use babel/preset-env 7.3.1 and it's `corejs` is not a top-level config option.

**Update**

I was able to make it work with a test project of which I tried to match your setup as best as possible. You can use this to slowly add complexity and modules that you use in your project to isolate the problem. This basic setup matches yours and works well. You can use this as a starting point.

package.json

```
{
  "name": "babel-transprile-error",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.3",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.4.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.4.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-arrow-functions": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-parameters": "^7.4.3",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.4.3",
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.4.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.4.3",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.4.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.5",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.6.0",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "webpack": "^4.30.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.1"
  }
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    entry: ["@babel/polyfill", './src/page/index.js'],

    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname,'dist'),
        publicPath: '/',
        filename: 'myapp/static/js/[name]/bundle.js'
    },
    devtool: 'source-map',
    module: require("./config/loaders.js"),
    devServer:{
        open: true,
        publicPath: '/',
        historyApiFallback: true,
        disableHostCheck: true
    },
    plugins: [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: "[name].css",
            chunkFilename: "[id].css"
        }),
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            fetch: "isomorphic-fetch",
        })
    ]
};
```

.babelrc

```
{
  "presets": [
    // ["@babel/env",
    //   {
    //     "targets": {
    //       "browsers": "ie 11"
    //     },
    //     "useBuiltIns": "usage",
    //     "corejs": "3.0.1",
    //   }
    // ],
    ["@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "useBuiltIns": "entry",
        "corejs": "3.0.1",
      }],
    "@babel/react"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    ["@babel/transform-runtime"],
    ["@babel/plugin-transform-parameters"],
    ["@babel/plugin-transform-arrow-functions"],
    [
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators",
      {
        "legacy": true
      }
    ],
    [
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
      {
        "loose": true
      }
    ],
  ]
}
```

src/page/index.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class someComponent extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    method(e = {}) {
        console.log(e);

        var nn = function(e={}) {
            const {baseClasses: t, newClasses: n, Component: r} = e;
            if (!n)
                return t;
            const a = At()({}, t);
            return Object.keys(n).forEach(e=>{
                    n[e] && (a[e] = `${t[e]} ${n[e]}`)
                }
            ), a
        };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div onClick={ e => { this.method(e) }}/>
        )
    }
}

export default someComponent;
```

config/loaders.js

```
module.exports = {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
            // exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
        },
        {
            test: /\.(css|less)$/,
            use: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "less-loader"]
        },
        {
            test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
            use: [
                {
                    loader: 'url-loader',
                    options: {
                        limit: 500, //small than 500 use url, otherwise use base64
                        outputPath:'inquiry/static/img/'
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
            use: [{
                loader: 'file-loader',
                options: {
                    outputPath: 'myapp/static/fonts/'
                }
            }]

        }
    ]
};
```

Comment: It doesn't work.  Still exist arrow functions and default parameters.

Comment: ```j=(e,t={})=>n=>{const{withTheme:r=!1,flip:o=null,name:s}=t,u=i()(t,["withTheme","flip","name"])```

Comment: If I dont provide corejs version, ```npm run deploy``` will encounter some error. ERROR INFO:  ```WARNING: We noticed you're using the `useBuiltIns` option without declaring a core-js version. Currently, we assume version 2.x when no version is passed. Since this default version will likely change in future versions of Babel, we recommend explicitly setting the core-js version you are using via the `corejs` option.```

Comment: I think we are not receiving that error about corejs because we use the module commonjs. I'll have another look.

Comment: Can you also check the version numbers I provided in the package.json?

Comment: I have kept all the versions consistent with yours, but still doesn't working.  orz

Comment: Ok i've added all my testing code that matches your setup. I suggest you run it next to your project, search for the differences and maybe try to add external dependencies that you use that might affect the behaviour. Usually my strategy to debug these kind of problems is to bring it down to the bare minimum and slowly build your setup, to isolate the problem.

Comment: I just added ```debug:true``` to preset-env and found that there is ```Import of core-js was not found.``` for each js file

Comment: Right, so did you manage to make it work? It's strange, because core-js module is a dependency of @babel/polyfill.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have solved this problem. The cause is that I use Meterial UI and in this lib there are two kinds of code, one follows ES6 rules and another follows ES5. And some of the components were imported automatically with ES6 version and they are not compiled by Babel. That's why it always have arrow functions in my bundle.js.

Answer (score 3):

I am using webpack 5, and setting target to es5 in `webpack.config.js` solved the problem for me.

```
module.exports = {
    target: 'es5',
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it caused by some packages that contains default parameters. So I fixed that by include `node_modules` in `babel-loader`:

```
    {
      test: /\.(jsx?)$/,
      use: {
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
          presets: ['@babel/env', '@babel/react'],
          plugins: [
            '@babel/plugin-transform-runtime',
            [
              '@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties',
              {
                loose: true
              }
            ],
            ['@babel/plugin-proposal-export-default-from'],
            '@babel/plugin-transform-parameters'
          ]
        }
      }
      /** Include the node_modules folder to fix !! **/
      // exclude: /node_modules/         // <== Here is the magic works !
    },
```